# How to redirect from subdomain with urlrewrite in java

Tags: java, redirect, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm trying to redirect from subdomain `m.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com/mobile`
I'm using [urlrewrite library](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) in my Java project.

What is the best way to do this?